# How compatible are ceiling fan drop rods?

Tags: ceiling-fan

My wife found a ceiling fan she loves from Minka Aire. We need a 12" drop rod. I cannot, for the life of me, find a drop rod in the brushed carbon color of the fan. I can find lots of knock-offs out there- Are drop rods truly incompatible between manufacturers?

Comment: Worst case, can you just cover a Minka Aire drop rod with a vinyl wrap that matches your chosen color?

Comment: How compatible are tires? How compatible are carrots? Either they're the right size and shape or they aren't.... or you _make_ them so. This is really a shopping question. Read labels and measure features.

Comment: A coordinating spray paint would do fine, also.

Answer (score 3):

There's certainly no guarantee they *are* compatible.

But this is a relatively simple part, strictly mechanical. You should be able to compare the ends of the original rod and the new one, if you have them both on hand, and see if the new one will fit properly.

Personally, I'd go to a lighting specialty store, explain what I need, and let them do the work to find a match. It may cost a bit more, but the time saved may be worth it.

Answer (score 1):

With most of the new ceiling fans out there, the attachments at both ends, the hole in the drop rod with the removable pin, are the same. The big difference can be in the diamater of the drop rod. I have found new fans with 3/4" drop rods instead of the older, more common 1/2" ones. Make sure you know what size you need before buying anything.